# How to use Alt+Backspace in vim command line to delete entire words?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keypress in the vim command line?  It gets unruly when you have to use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on something like `/very/long/file/path` multiple times, instead of using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete entire words.

Comment: Sorry guys I think I'm using `vim commandline` wrongly, since none of the answers seem to work. I'm talking about the line at bottom of screen which appears when you press `:` in normal mode, the one you type `:set` and other things into.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using instead `<c-w>` (which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>) to erase words or `<c-u>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd>) to delete lines.

Comment: Just typing in the same answer :D. For addition Vim's command bar works almost the same as in Terminal (so C-H, C-K, C-N, C-P also works). And if @senthil still prefer Alt + BS then it is `cmap <a-bs> <c-w>`

Comment: `<c-w>` and the others works great. Thanks @skeept and @tungd.

Comment: correct, but not what the op asked for ... chk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59702513/65706

Answer (score 3):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-Backspace_to_delete_previous_word

`:imap <C-BS> <C-W>`

sets ctrl backspace, i have to look at how to do alt

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's as easy as:

```hs
if has('gui_running')
    inoremap <M-BS> <C-W>
    cnoremap <M-BS> <C-W>
else
    inoremap <Esc><BS> <C-W>
    cnoremap <Esc><BS> <C-W>
endif
```

The trick here is to know, given a hypothetical <kbd>foo</kbd> key, that after pressing a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>foo</kbd> combination, many terminals will send an Escape code followed by <kbd>foo</kbd>. Apparently there are exceptions — some terminals do send something that vim can recognize as <kbd>Alt</kbd>. But if a `inoremap <M-BS> <C-W>` mapping doesn't work for you in terminal, then most likely your terminal sends an Esc instead, so the combination `inoremap <Esc><BS> <C-W>` should work for you.

You can read more about that in vim documentation by evaluating `:help map-alt-keys`

Comment: Please note that `cnoremap` should be used instead of `imap`, because the OP asked about using the `<M-BS>` keypress in command mode.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer!  One more suggestion, `inoremap` should be used instead of `imap`.  In general, recursive mappings are needed quite rarely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the end of the path you can hit `B` followed by a `dW` (case matters).  This will jump you to the beginning of the word (ignoring the slashes) and subsequently delete the word (again ignoring the slashes).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see your point here. If I'm already out of insert mode, which pressing opt+<backspace> does, then I could use `dW`. This doesn't work for me unless I first go to the [b]eggining of the word by pressing `b`. So the command is: `bdW`

Answer (score 1):

Vim is unable to receive alt input. skeept's answer seems to be the best alternative.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11665408/4669158):

> The Alt/Meta key is problematic in Vim and most terminals, see this answer of mine for an overview of the situation (the situation is the same for Meta and Alt).
>
> In short, Vim doesn't receive Alt at all: hitting Alt+Backspace is exactly the same as hitting Backspace.
>
> Anyway, it will be better for you in the long term to learn and get accustomed to Vim's default key-mappings.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked as right does not correspond to the behaviour in most UI editors for Alt + BackSpace. The vim shortcut which correspond to this behaviour is `db` - aka delete back ( a word ?! ), `dw` would delete word forth, which would be the (Altr or Ctrl ) Del shortcut in most ui programs.
Those work basically the same way as the `w` - move the cursor to the words beginnings and `b`, move the cursor back to the words beginning ...

Disclaimer: I have used for more than 10 years my [.vimrc](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/ysg-confs/blob/master/.vimrc.host-name). , which might have some freaky twist which changes the default behaviour as well ...

Answer (score -1):

x then w should backspace per word as well.
d then w will also delete the current word the cursor is on.