# alt+backspace to delete words in vim

Tags: customization, vim

How can I remap `alt+backspace` to delete words like native *NIX text manipulation? I checked out this thread: [Using alt+backspace key in vim command line to delete by words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039405/using-altbackspace-key-in-vim-command-line-to-delete-by-words)

And the examples like: `cmap <a-bs> <c-w>` and `:imap <A-BS> <C-W>` don't do anything. And the accepted answer was actually to not even remap it, but to use `ctrl+w`. Since VIM's `alt+backspace` doesn't do anything I'd rather remap it to something I'm used to.

I'm using terminal based VIM (specifically in iTerm)

Comment: The first step is to find out what your terminal does with the key combination. Start vim, go into insert mode, type Ctrl-V followed by backspace, then another Ctrl-V followed by Alt-backspace. If it prints the same thing for both, you're out of luck. Otherwise, the map command should work if you type Ctrl-V Alt-Backspace in the `:map` command instead of `<A-BS>`.

Comment: visual mode then backspace highlights 1 character. Visual mode then `alt+backspace` gets out of visual mode, so they don't do the same thing. Also, I don't want to be in visual mode to do `alt+backspace`. That defeats the ease of deletion i was looking for (like `dd`), so, now what?

Comment: I didn't want you to be in visual mode either. Ctrl-V in insert mode is not supposed to go into visual mode. You must have a weird mapping (`:imap <C-V>`) or you weren't in insert mode when you did it.

Comment: Oh, i see. I wasn't in insert mode. Skipped that. So, in insert mode and pressing ctrl+v then backspace I get `^?` and doing ctrl+v in insert mode then alt+backspace doesn't really do anything. Just moves the cursor back 1 position.

Comment: Well, it's good news that they do different things, so there's a chance of distinguishing them. But I don't know what to do when Ctrl-V doesn't protect a special key. Maybe try typing Ctrl-V Alt-Backspace elsewhere - at the vi `:` prompt, at your shell prompt, inside a `cat >/dev/null` command... it must be sending something to the terminal, we just don't know what it is.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196357/making-iterm-to-translate-meta-key-in-the-same-way-as-in-other-oses) can offer some assistance on the meta key in iTerm?

Comment: So, @AlanCurry, doing it at the `:` just does `^` for for `ctrl+v` then doing `alt+backspace` clears that out

Comment: @Conner I already have my meta key set to alt so I can do things like `alt+b` and `alt+f` to jump back and forwards between words

Comment: You know all these keybindings you're talking about are emacs-based, right? Are you sure you want to use vi[m] at all? How about the bash prompt? If Alt-Backspace works there, see how it likes it with a Ctrl-V.

Comment: @AlanCurry, your suggestion of doing `Ctrl-V backspace` and `Ctrl-V Alt-backspace` and then doing `:map` worked perfectly for me (OSX iTerm2 vim). If you posted it as an answer I'd definitely upvote it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

On macOS with iTerm2, I have the option keys mapped to +Esc (like many people), and I found that pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> actually was interpreted by vim as an <kbd>Escape</kbd> press followed by a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> press, so the following binding worked perfectly for me; I recommend trying it even if your configuration is different than mine, just in case it works for you!

```
:imap <Esc><BS> <C-w>
```

Comment: Thanx @Chrisopher After searching for hours and trying many things, this is what worked for on catalina with zsh. Added in vimrc `imap <Esc><BS> <C-w>.

Comment: Just want to say thank you, I've been looking for this for dayz

Answer (score 5):

The Alt/Meta key is problematic in Vim and most terminals, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224269/546861) for an overview of the situation (the situation is the same for `Meta` and `Alt`).

In short, Vim doesn't receive `Alt` at all: hitting `Alt+Backspace` is exactly the same as hitting `Backspace`.

Anyway, it will be better for you in the long term to learn and get accustomed to Vim's default key-mappings.

Comment: I already am, but as with all custom mappings it's to make it easier or else there wouldn't be a way to make custom mappings and overrides :)

Comment: Yes and no. I see custom mappings as ways to augment Vim, mainly. Anyway, the Alt key doesn't exist for Vim so you'll have to find another mapping (which defeats your purpose) or get used to `<C-w>`.

Comment: I am used to having to use it, it's just super awkward finger placement on a Mac laptop.

Comment: For me Vim sees <ESC><BS> which makes the behavior pretty easy to explain (exit insert, move left one).

Comment: "It will be better for you" is subjective. Don't make assumptions about others. "My recommended alternative" is a more appropriate beginning to that last sentence.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat no it is not subjective at all. Learning one's tool properly is always better than not learning it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on OSX, [macvim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) uses the standard key bindings, so pressing `Alt+Backspace` will delete the entire word. Same goes for navigating between words with `Alt+RightArrow` and `Alt+LeftArrow`.